# How to change PHP version in a Symfony 4 project?

Tags: php, symfony

I want to change the PHP version because my version is 7.1.23 and I need to upgrade to 7.2 for install a package that I want to use.

I'm using MAMP on Macbook Pro.
Here's what I've done :

I've add this line in this .bash_profile file :

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.14/bin:$PATH
```

In the composer.json file I've update the version to

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.14"
```

I've create a .php-version in the project directory. It contains :

```
7.2
```

If I do "php -v" in my terminal I've that :

```
~ php -v
PHP 7.2.14 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2019 12:25:00) ( NTS )
```

When I launch my project with "symfony serve", that give me :

```
The Web server is using PHP CGI 7.2.14                                                                            
      https://127.0.0.1:8000
```

But when I want to make "composer update" or "symfony local:php:list" it return me that I'm still using PHP version (7.1.23).

How can I finally upgrade the version ?

Here's a screen from my terminal :

[image]

Comment: mh, does local:php:list at least list your second php version? also, why does your .php-version contain 7.2 and not 7.2.14?

Comment: @Jakumi Yes, I've every PHP version ( 5, 7, 7.0.24, 7.1.10, ... ) but that's the version 7.1.23 who is selected. But the version 7.2.14 is underlined. I've change the .php-version for try, but before it was 7.2.14 and that's doesn't change

Answer (score 1):

okay, so as far as I can tell, your symfony command already uses 7.2.14 (highlighted version in first column, ignore the `*` in the last column, it only tells what is the system's default), since it says so on `symfony serve`.

composer however doesn't, which is *most likely* due to the fact that composer is a php script that is made executable via a hash bang at the very first line of the file (and the x chmod):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

which essentially says, "run me with the interpreter/command /usr/bin/php". There are other variants of composer around, some have `#!/usr/bin/env php` which will look for  a php in the PATH variable and use that instead.

However, to fix this, I propose these reasonable options

- run composer with an explicit php (check composer path with `which composer`):

  ```
    php /usr/bin/composer update
  ```

  which obviously is a bit inconvenient, or
- just install another composer, which is most likely more recent anyway and add it to your PATH before `/usr/bin` like you did with your alternative php version, which will allow you to run it standalone/independent, or
- use the symfony script to run composer:

  ```
  symfony composer update
  ```

  disclaimer. I haven't actually tried this, but I would be surprised if this didn't run composer with the correct php version...

Comment: Ok. I tried to symfony run composer update. This ran composer but again with the wrong php version. Anyway. this solution solved my problem ;). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by creating a file ".php-version" that contains the php version number (ex : 8.1.2)  in the project directory